# Twitter boot strap menu - responsive issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Is there a way to make it so that when the navigation shrinks down all or any of the drop down menus are expanded? thus when the user touches the navigation and it drops down all the drop down navigation items are already fully expanded?

I assumed this was a default behaviour but this seems to not be the case for me.

Instead my navigation looks as such:

[image: Image Example]

I had to hover over Menu item to get that secondary menu. Is there a way to have this and all other drop down menus already expanded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer to fix this is to do the following: [Which is seen here.](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4550#issuecomment-10398831)

```
@media (max-width: 980px) {
  .dropdown ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

This is for version **2.2.2**

Answer (score 0):

It was only starting in version 2.2 that the behavior you want was replaced by the current behavior of having dropdowns be collapsed/collapsible in a collapsible navbar.

I threw together the following workaround, which seems to do the trick:

```
$('.nav-collapse').on('show', function (e) {
  var $dropdowns = $(this).find('.dropdown');
  setTimeout(function () {
    $dropdowns.addClass('open')
  });
});
```

The reason for the `setTimeout` is because otherwise the original **click** event which triggered opening the navbar will end up closing the dropdowns again when it propagates up to the `<html>` element.